# Как объединить 2 потока в Asyncio?

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio, observer

Есть 2 скрипта:
1- Observer - получает событие об изменении файла и читает сам файл.
Пример: В директории 'C:\ForTest' лежит файл text.txt
Если мы что-то напишем в в файл text.txt и сохраним его, то в консоль должно выводиться: путь к файлу, который изменен, и текст из файла.
2- Стандартный бот на AIOGram
Как объединить 2 потока, чтобы при работающем боте, работал скрипт Observer?

Пробовала вот так, через добавление задачи, до полной реализации, но при этом бот работает, а файлы не читаются:

```
import asyncio
import logging
from datetime import datetime

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, html, F
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.filters import Command, CommandObject
from aiogram.types import FSInputFile, URLInputFile, BufferedInputFile
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hide_link

from config import config
import Handlers
from sqlFile import db, sql, create_sql

##########
import time

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

##########

bot = Bot(token=config['token'], parse_mode="HTML")
storage: MemoryStorage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(storage=storage)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
create_sql()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


##########
class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.txt", "*.jpg"]

    def process(self, event):
        """
        event.event_type
            'modified' | 'created' | 'moved' | 'deleted'
        event.is_directory
            True | False
        event.src_path
            path/to/observed/file
        """
        # print(event.src_path, event.event_type)
        out = str(event.src_path)
        with open(out, "r") as t1:
            text = t1.read()
        print(out)
        print(text)

    def on_modified(self, event):
        self.process(event)

    def on_created(self, event):
        self.process(event)


##########
async def observer_run():
    args = 'C:\\ForTest'
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(), path=args if args else '.')
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()


async def main():
    dp.include_router(Handlers.user_router)
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
    loop.run_until_complete(observer_run())
```

Answer (score 1):

Это не потоки, а таски. паралельно ожидать таски можно через https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather или asyncio.wait

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(asyncio.gather(main(),observer_run())
```